# How to change text color within sentence?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code:

```
from functools import partial

def x_in_y(word, inner):
    return inner in word

words = [
    ('mann', 'men'),
    ('connaction', 'connection'),
    ('tee', 'tea'),
    ('rigt', 'right'),
    ('putt', 'putt'),
    ('yewrwe','tyte')
]

sentence=['this mann is my son','the connaction is unstable','my tee is getting cold','put your hands down','rigt now','right behind my back']

for wrong,correct in words:
    filtered_names = filter(partial(x_in_y, inner=wrong), sentence)
    next_elem = next(filtered_names, None)
    if next_elem:
        print(f"Typo: {wrong} 'should be {correct}'")
        print(next_elem)
    for name in filtered_names:
        print(name)
```

Output:

```
Typo: mann 'should be men'
this mann is my son
Typo: connaction 'should be connection'
the connaction is unstable
Typo: tee 'should be tea'
my tee is getting cold
Typo: rigt 'should be right'
rigt now
```

I hope to change the text color of the typo only.

Like this:

```
Typo: mann 'should be men'
this →mann←red  is my son
Typo: connaction 'should be connection'
the →connaction←red is unstable
Typo: tee 'should be tea'
my →tee←red is getting cold
Typo: rigt 'should be right'
→rigt←red now
```

How to do that? I can only change the color for the whole sentence. I don't know how to change only a portion of the text. Should I use `str.replace` function or something?

Can anyone help me out or give me a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use `.replace`, replacing the `wrong` word with the `correct` word *plus* [`colorama`](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/)'s ANSI escape sequences to print colored terminal text.

Code:

```py
from colorama import init, Fore, Style
init()

...

for wrong, correct in words:
    ...
    if next_elem:
        print(f"Typo: {wrong} 'should be {correct}'")
        print(next_elem.replace(wrong, f"{Fore.RED}{wrong}{Style.RESET_ALL}"))
    ...
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi Thank you for helping me out. But when i tried to "pip install colorama", output still shows "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'colorama'" .Why?

Comment: @briiipo You have to install it using the same Python that you use to run your app/script. If you are using a virtual environment (virtualenv, venv, etc.), you need to install it in that same env. If you use `python myscript.py` to run your script, try `python -m pip install colorama`. If you use `python3 myscript.py` to run your script, try `python3 -m pip install colorama`. If you use some IDE like VS Code or Pycharm, then you need to install it in that IDE's same Python env.

Comment: Thanks!Many Thanks! My problem solved! Your suggestion is really helpful.